# PHPMailer 6.2 stream_socket_client

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer, apache2.4, stream-socket-client

I switched over to using PHPMailer 6.2 (which is the master version, and most recent version).

I am using Apache 2.4 on a Windows Server 2019.  The version of PHP I am using is 7.4.12.

Following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t0zwgJrSHd4

I am not having much luck using the below code:

```
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;

require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';
require 'phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php';
require 'phpmailer/class.smtp.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->SMTPDebug = 4;  

$mail->isSMTP(); 
$mail->Host = 'xx.x.x.xxx'; 
$mail->SMTPAuth = false; // <- just changed to false
$mail->Username = 'mycompany@email.com'; 
$mail->Password = 'mypassword';  
$mail->Port = 25;  
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
// update
$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
    'ssl' => array(
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true
    )
);   
// end update

$mail->setFrom('mycompany@email.com', 'Mailer');
$mail->addAddress('myoutsidefacingemail@gmail.com', 'TEST'); 
$mail->addReplyTo('mycompany@email.com', 'Information');
$mail->addCC('mycoworker@email.com');

$mail->isHTML(true);  

$mail->Subject = 'This is a test subject';
$mail->Body    = '<h1>This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b></h1>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->send()) {
  echo 'Message could not be sent.';
  echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo 'Message has been sent';
}
?>
```

I have edited this question as I have made some updates (see above code).

Using the above, I can send email internally, on our network.

The problem is sending external email.

Here is the error message I am receiving when trying to send to my gmail (I did not paste the full error message, just the last few lines):

```
2021-01-21 21:02:26 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2021-01-21 21:02:26 SMTP INBOUND: "221 2.0.0 Service closing transmission channel"
2021-01-21 21:02:26 SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 Service closing transmission channel
2021-01-21 21:02:26 Connection: closed
SMTP Error: The following recipients failed: myoutsidefacingemail@gmail.com: 
SMTP; Unable to relay recipient in non-accepted domain
Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP Error: The following recipients failed: myoutsidefacingemail@gmail.com: SMTP; Unable to relay recipient in non-accepted domain
```

Comment: STARTTLS mode is much better for tracking down TLS issues, as you've found. The interesting part of that output is `certificate verify failed`. The usual reasons for this error are that the certificate has expired, it doesn't match the expected name, or that your CA certificate bundle is outdated. See the troubleshooting guide for more on those.

Comment: @Synchro - How do I set STARTTLS?  Also, what certificates is the error message referring to?  The ssl certificates?  We did just recently install new certificates.  Could that be the issue?

Comment: STARTTLS mode is what you get when you set `SMTPSecure = 'tls'`, so you're already doing that. It's the certificate presented by the mail server, nothing to do with the one you're using to serve your site. Your server will have a collection of CA certificates (usually provided by the OS) that it uses to verify the mail server's certificate.

Comment: @Synchro - I made some updates.  I was able to send internal facing email.  The problem was sending external emails.  Any thoughts?

Comment: The most likely issue is outdated CA certs. Compare results using OpenSSL and PHP. Try getting PHP to use an updated CA cert bundle - see the guide for how to do that. Generally, make sure your server is fully updated.